# How to find the equilibrium points and stability of a system of two diff. equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, jacobian, stability-in-odes

I'm having a hard time working this out.

My system discribes the evolution of the population of $2$ species:
$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = (a - bP - kQ)P,
\\
\frac{dQ}{dt} = (c - dQ - lP)Q.
$$
As i understand, to find the equilibrium point i must do $P'(t) = Q'(t) = 0$, right?
With this two equations i should get 4 equilibrium points.
$$
(a - bP - kQ)P = 0,
(c - dQ - lP)Q = 0.
$$
The only way i found to work this around was:

1. if I consider $P=0$, I get $(0, \frac{c}{d})$.
2. if I consider $Q=0$, I get $(\frac{a}{b}, 0)$.
3. if I consider $P=0$ and $Q=0$, I get $(0,0)$.
4. ?

Is what i did remotely correct? If not, how do i do this?

For the stability I know I have to do the **Jacobian matrix** and I think I can do it once I have the $4$ equilibrium points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks right. Just finish the 4th case.

Comment: If $P\ne0$ and $Q\ne0$, you can divide by $P$ in the first equation and by $Q$ in the second equation. That leaves you with 2 linear equations in 2 variables.

Comment: @Carl, Thanks for the input, that makes sense. I did what you suggested and got: P=(ad-ck)/(bd-kl) and Q=(bc-al)/(bd-kl). For the Jacobian Matrix it might be a bit confusing with all this letters. Hope i'm on the right track. Thanks again.